# Issue on parsing logs using regex

Tags: regex

I have tried separating the wowza logs using regex for data analysis, but I couldn't separate the section below.

I need a **SINGLE regex pattern** that would satisfy below both log formats.

Format 1:

```
live wowz://test1.example.com:443/live/_definst_/demo01|wowz://test2.example.com:443/live/_definst_/demo01 test
```

Format 2:

```
live demo01 test
```

I am trying to split the line on the 3 parameters and capturing them in the groups `app`, `streamname` and `id`, but `streamname` should only capture the text after the last `/`.

This is what I've tried:

`(?<stream_name>[^/]+)$` --> Using this pattern I could only separate the format 1 "wowz" section. Not entire Format 1 example mentioned above.

Expected Output

{

```
"app": [
    [
        "live"
    ]
],
"streamname": [
    [
        "demo1"
    ]
],
"id": [
    [
        "test"
    ]
]
```

}

Comment: Can you elaborate on what lines it should match? i.e: why not any line starting with `live`? Or why would you use `[^/]+` to match a line that actually has slashes?

Comment: @maraiano , I need to split "demo1" from both format logs using single regular expression.

expected output:

{
  "app": [
    [
      "live"
    ]
  ],
  "streamname": [
    [
      "demo1"
    ]
  ],
  "id": [
    [
      "test"
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: Try [`^(?<app>\S+) (?:\S*/)?(?<streamname>\S+) (?<id>\S+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/qY5wX0/1) ... Or **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33828858/edit)** your question showing the relevant part of your log and expected output in the body of your post

Comment: Still not clear what has to be separed from what. "demo1" means and alfanumeric id of any length? Expand the question please

Comment: @maraino, Solution works for me. If you post the same in solution tag, I will mark it as Correct answer

Comment: As always, if you don't specify what should *not* match, a safe and easy bet is the regex `.*`

Comment: @KMG I edited your question adding a line of what I interpreted that should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you specified using the following regex:

```
^(?<app>\S+) (?:\S*/)?(?<streamname>\S+) (?<id>\S+)$
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/qY5wX0/1)</kbd>

---

- `\S+` matches any number of characters except whitespace.
- `(?:\S*/)?` to optionally consume the characters in the second parameter up to the last `/`. This is not included in the group, so it won't be captured.

Comment: thanks, Its solved my Problem. I marked it as Correct Answer

Comment: Could you please share some link to learn regex pattern ?. Thanks once again for your kindly help

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html This is the best IMO. It may take some time reading it, but that's the time you need so you can learn regex